# How can a Middle-Age spy traveller hide as many ropes and gags as possible on themselves?

Tags: medieval, crime, stealth

As I recalled about some [Mermaids being tied up](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/213358/80336), I remembered some [stealth game moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desperados_III) where the heroes, in order to have free moments wandering around without those annoying guards and honest citizens, could tie up a village to get their job done. Yes I mean it, *you could tie up all the town inhabitants*.

### The infamous gang of roast trussers

I'm designing a reminiscence of such moments through the infamous ragtag "gang of the roast trussers". Roaming through roughly 12-13th century British medieval fantasy lands, these guys are truly evil : They tie up seemingly random people, rob them their freedom of movements on top of their belongings, then leave towards new lands. Be it a lone traveller, a caravan or even small villages, no one is spared. Everyone wonder why they don't kill up the victims, but it has become part of their legend.

And they are scenariously<sup>1</sup> damn good at it : Each of their member have a wide range of sneaking skills to divide, conquer and tie up without anyone else noticing. These skills goes from the near-invisible ninja to the good-looking gentleman/woman whom you should definitely (not) trust. My question is about the latter one.

### Their charms are mind-binding

*The people's description will be blurred. It's not about that 1.84m tall blond man, who wears X things, but more a general approach to this issue, regardless of gender. Moreover, the tales have all blurred who they actually were or how many they were. Some say they were 3, others 10! And some say even [enough to choke a whole sea port!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%27est_la_sardine_qui_a_bouch%C3%A9_le_port_de_Marseille).*

Some of the members are effectively Trojan horses on legs. Good looking and naturally charming, they often take the disguise of seducing travelers (oftentimes merchants), through both clothes, fake documents and enchanting smiles. While people say their primary targets are nobles, it is not really the case since they are quite hard to reach with all their guards around. They only do so when a good opportunity shows up, with long and careful planning beforehand.

In order to do their deeds, their attire are adapted to best match the current job, as well as their manners and behaviors. It can come even to the point of crossdressing, which means that men can dress up as women and women as men if necessary.

### Wrapping up the question

So here comes the question : In order to tie up people on the spot, the "spies" of this gang need to have ropes, a tranquilizant vial to quickly subdue people, and gags so that when they wake up, people "scream quietly" for guards (we wouldn't want to disturb them during their work after all :p!). They almost always carry a locked chest containing everything for their deeds, but it is tedious (and suspicious) to carry it all the time or to have to go back and forth to retrieve supplies. Therefore the goal is to have them have as much as possible equipment on themselves.

I have already a solution (literally and non-litterally) for the vial, so what's left are ropes and gags. Therefore... **How can these people hide as much as ropes and gags as possible on themselves?**

I will determine what would be the best answers roughly from this : by the number of individuals that can be constrained before restocking (per solution type), how well the equipment can be hidden and adapted to different situations<sup>2</sup>, and to a lesser extent how easy/fast tying kits can be pulled out and how fast/easy they can be restocked.

Know they have a standard procedure for tying up people : They are laid down, face towards the ground. The hands are bound back with one rope, the feet with another, and another joins the two ropes together to prevent people from wriggling away. Therefore a total of three ropes are needed for an individual. People are not blindfolded, but they are silenced, so one gag is needed per person. The gag can be anything you can think of : Rope, tissue...

Also consider that because they use their charms to get people where they want, they might get close to their victims, up to the intimate zone (Without removing clothes, if you wonder). This might potentially reveal their tools to them, ruining their infiltration, so be careful about this. If necessary, they can avoid some parts of their body being touched, if that's not too big or easy to reach (ie. their back, legs and feet, ...).

For the sake of the question's simplicity and because they are not [*that* evil](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WouldntHurtAChild) (or are they?), children are spared from this, so you don't need to account different rope sizes. Also, remember they target more the lower and middle classes, as they don't need very specific preparations to wrap up a personal guard, so focus on these classes whenever possible.

---

<sup>1</sup> *: Read by this that their supernatural efficiency at tying up so many people and not getting caught is happily handwaved by the power of myths, legends and -most importantly- scenarium. Don't focus too much on this, please :).*

<sup>2</sup> *: I'm looking for answers that can work up as standard equipment. Things that work for very specific situations like, I don't know... a "rope pan" only for when you're in a kitchen is less interesting for me :). Yeah, I know, pretty bad example, but you get the gist."*

Comment: In a medieval setting I'd assume cloaks are used regularly. Also people had bags. What just stops them from hiding like a basic tool on their body to subdue the person then open up the bag and tie the person? That case anything from a lasso, some dart gun contraption, big stick to knock them out...etc can be used. Why bother have the rope on hand while you can use a 100 things to get them under you control? Also consider just wrapping rope around them between 2 layers of clothing to even add more ropes to use. 
I don't get it

Comment: @Seallussus That's worth an answer, especially the cloak as I wonder how you hide them under it :). To help you understand why I asked this, I'll give some flaws here and there. For the ropes between layers of clothing : How do you explain your miraculous diet and oversized clothes when you pass through a village? Also, if you get touched, you'll quickly notice the gaps and stiffness caused by the ropes.[...]

Comment: [...] Bags can get checked by guards or militias, and being found with many ropes when the infamous roast trussers are known running around ... Works as well for the locked chest, which would need to be outside views. Using ropes over other things are explained through the first paragraph. Do you wish more explanations about why ropes :)?

Comment: This seems to be all over the place. Like you are looking for some sort of tactical super duper outfit. Probably not gonna happen. It's like you wear a suit you can't wear fully body armor and have access to mag pouches for ammunition. You wear tactical stuff but that gives you away. My point is that you can't have your cake and eat it.
For example. Why you thinking about being touched? You hide the ropes on the body until you strike the victim and go on your way. The purpose is to get close enough to do it then blind in. You wanna be able to do that all the time all over the place? 1/2

Comment: 2/2 Guards and being searching is not an issue. You can hide the ropes in a lot of stuff. They don't have scanning machines. You can explain it with a profession. Also cities are only a part of it. Even then just get past the check point and once in the city they won't go around searching everyone. If someone is close enough to check your body then you have another problem. Also ropes are not that thick to be a problem under the clothing. Social statues is a thing. If a knight with a squire is not gonna be bothered, same with rich merchants...etc. 
I feel you want to complicate the matter.

Comment: @Seallussus Perhaps you think I'm looking for spytech-3000 equipment because I told I "wish" to maximize 4 criterias? I added this part because there's a need to sort answers (otherwise it's opinion-based), more than a filter you need to pass through :|.

Answer (score 4):

Middle-aged medieval traveler  sounds definitely like a perfect depiction of a travelling Catholic [Monk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monk#Western_Christianity) - they often wore a [girdle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girdle) (or a cord) as a common and unassuming part of their attire. Granted, that's not much of a length, but the rest can be hidden in a false belly - going by the best tradition of no one else than [Thomas Aquinas](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Aquinas), who was by all accounts [extremely obese](https://commongoodonline.org/thomas-aquinas-fat-in-body-muscular-in-mind-and-heart-offers-us-good-theology/). It won't be noticed unless you do strip search of that group of travelling pious men, and people are naturally reluctant to molest the servants of the God...

Comment: Let's all now pray for the rope, uh Lord! Yes, Lord! I'm just wondering how do you explain how miraculously efficient your "diet" is. You know, as you tie up more and more people :p.

Comment: @Tortliena Funny you should say that, because you can't spell "diet" without "die"

Answer (score 2):

### Feminine "fashion"

[image: Corset ... with 18 victims' worth of rope]

Corsets, bustles, brassieres, stockings, multiple layers of heavy skirts ... who can keep track of all the varieties of torture to which the medieval woman was subject?  If you make them out of ropes suitable for tying people up, they may look a little more uncomfortable than the usual models -- be careful you don't start a fashion trend!  Your cross-dressing men should come out of these encounters with a heightened regard for the travails of the fairer sex.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever seen those old pictures of the dawn of bicycle races, where there were no support cars and the athletes had to carry the spare tubes with them, wrapped around their torso?

Well, that's a solution you can copy: a few turns up-right to down-left and then crossed from up-left to down-right, closing with some around the waist loops can give you a decent length of rope, with the added benefit of acting like or being disguised as an additional protection because you never know when you will stumble in a rogue blade.